# On ethics and civilizations?

Tags: ethics

Can ethics be considered as an interface between where the society seems him/her to be versus where the individual is?

Consider this I am 40 but look in my 20s naturally. This makes it difficult to set a standard to me. If this was taken as the norm of a civilization then how would it impact the idea of ethics in different civilizations? (In terms of likelihood of a particular ethic construction).

Who are some philosophers with this line of thought and where can I read them up?